# Get a list of computers connected via RDP

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rdp

I need to count the number of RDP connections with the same name of the PC. I'm going to make a limit on the number of simultaneous connections using a bat file (cmd).

What command or script can get the names of all the computers connected to the terminal server? This information is displayed in the Task Manager, but how to get this list via a script?

Comment: Take a look at [the Get-RDUserSession cmdlet for powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj215497.aspx).

Comment: @LynnCrumbling, I do not have the ability to use powershell on this server

Comment: I think that you're stuck with WMI. But in order to even leverage that, you're still going to be execute a script interpreter of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Try;

query session /server:Server01

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490800.aspx

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.

Comment: @user3175347 , this get only usernames (logins), but i need clientnames (computers)